# onInstalled event does not fire when updating from MV2 to MV3 if MV2 old version has already registred a service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Trying to update a MV2 extension to MV3 I need to convert all localStorage items into chrome.storage items.

So in onInstalled event handler I open a new tab and I run a script for convertion.

Unfortunately the onInstalled event doesn't fire.
I did a try commenting the SW registration code in MV2 background.js and the onInstalled event fire!

How can I overcame this issue.

This is the code:

manifest.json MV2 version 0.0.0.1:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "99.0.0.0",
    "name": "Prova",
    "short_name": "Prova",
    "description": "foo bar",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["script/background.js"]
    },
    "icons": {
        "48": "img/icon48.png"
    },
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "chrome_style": true,
        "open_in_tab": true
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

background.js MV2 version 0.0.0.1

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function handleInstalled(details) {
    if (details.reason == "install")
        console.log('installED!')
    else if (details.reason == "update")
        console.log('Updated from version: ' + details.previousVersion)
});

localStorage.foo = '1';
localStorage.bar = '2';


//IF I REGISTER A SERVICE WORKER THE ONINSTALLED EVENT DON'T FIRE IN UPDATE PHASE!!!
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/myWorker.js', {scope: '/'})
        .then(registration => {
            console.log("Service Worker Registered")
        })
}
```

myWorker.js MV2 version 0.0.0.1

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
    console.log('Install phase done')
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (evt) {
    console.log('Activated!')
});

self.addEventListener('message', function(evt) {
    switch (evt.data.command) {
        case 'foo':
        break;

        case 'bar':
        break
    }
})
```

manifest.json MV3 version 0.0.0.2

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "102.0.0.0",
    "name": "Prova",
    "short_name": "Prova",
    "description": "foo bar",
    "version": "0.0.0.2",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "worker_wrapper.js"
    },
    "icons": {
        "48": "img/icon48.png"
    },
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "open_in_tab": true,
        "browser_style": true
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

worker_wrapper.js MV3 version 0.0.0.2

```
try {
    importScripts('/script/main.js')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

main.js MV3 version 0.0.0.2

```
        chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(handleInstalled);
        function handleInstalled(details) {
                console.log('Just entered in handleInstalled');
                if (details.reason == "install") {
                    clog('Estensione installata');
                } else if (details.reason == "update") {
                    let pv = details.previousVersion.replace(/\./g, '');
                    if (pv < '0002')
                        chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('convertStorage.html')})
                    else
                        console.log('Update from version: ' + details.previousVersion)
                }
        }
    
    **/*EDIT 2022-07-01 02:15 Rome Time*/**
self.addEventListener('install', function(evt) {
    console.log('Install phase done');
    chrome.storage.local.get('storageConverted', itm => {
        if (typeof itm?.storageConverted === 'undefined')
            chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('convertStorage.html')})
    })
});
```

convertStorage.js MV3 version 0.0.0.2

```
const oldLSVar = {
    'foo': 'number',
    'bar': 'string'
};
var tmpObj = {};
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    switch ( oldLSVar[key] ) {
        case 'number':
            tmpObj[key] = 1 * value;
            break;
        default:
            tmpObj[key] = value
    }
});

//EDIT 2022-06-30 17:00 Rome 
tmpObj['storConvertVer']=chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
chrome.storage.local.set(tmpObj, _ => {
    localStorage.clear();
    chrome.runtime.reload()
})
```

Comment: Try using self.oninstall event in MV3 as well.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant... and IT WORKS!!!
(I've edited the code again)
 This strange behavior can still be considered a bug or is it a necessary step in the migration from mv2 to mv3?

Comment: chrome.runtime.onInstalled not firing is definitely a bug.